# pycharm pytest hangs with python subprocess.run() using bash in interactive mode

Tags: pycharm, subprocess, pytest

I want to test a subprocess call in python that uses the interactive shell in linux. The interactive shell is necessary in order to utilise the aliases and path links in .bashrc.

In pycharm, running the following code in combination with pytest (right-click, Run 'pytest in...) causes the test process to hang.

```
import subprocess
def test_subprocess_with_interactive_bash():
    p = subprocess.run(['/bin/bash', '-i', '-c', 'ls'])
```

The python process can be stopped. The bash process remains visible in `top`. It needs to be killed with `kill -9 <pid>`

Running the code outside of pycharm (e.g. `pytest test_subprocess.py`) causes no problem. I could repeat this effect with the most recent versions of pycharm (2020.1) and pytest (5.4.2-py37_0).

Why does this happen? Is there a fix or workaround?